# El valor Null no se puede asignar a un miembro con el tipo System.Int32

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net, linq, aspx

Estoy haciendo una web en .net con aspx con sqlserver como base de datos, al llamar a un procedimiento almacenado hay ciertos campos que son enteros (int) pero hay ocasiones en las que me pueden venir como NULL, entonces si me viene como NULL me salta el siguiente error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'El valor Null no se puede asignar a un miembro con el tipo System.Int32 que es un tipo de valor que no acepta valores Null.'

Este es mi código:

```
    using (myApp ctx = new myApp())
    {
        var query = ctx.MY_STORED_PROCEDURE(tokenUsuario, Int32.Parse(idPrueba), Int32.Parse(idEstado));

        var jsonString = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       listadoIncidencias = jsonString.Serialize(query);

    }
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que al pasarle un valor NULL en el Int no me falle la web?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Echa un vistazo a los [tipos nullables](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)

Comment: Pero en el procedimiento como lo puedo poner?? ya que al intentar leer los datos me peta

Comment: suponiendo que los ids son los que te dan null, puedes en la propia funcion declarlos como 0 ej. `Function Query(string token, int idPrueba = 0, int idEstado = 0)` o al pasarselos como string por lo que veo en tu codigo es meter una condicion antes. `if(Int32.Parse(idPrueba) == null){ //setear valor}`

Comment: @Yandrak literalmente esta diciendo que debes controlar los valores nullos. Evalúa la carga, si es NULL, no lo cargas, ya que una de las llamadas, llega a ser NULL por X motivo. Incluso puedes luego, imprimirla y evaluar por que llego NULL y no cargada.

Comment: [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage = "_idUsuario", DbType = "int NOT NULL")]
  public string idUsuario
  {
   get
   {
    return this._idUsuario;
   }
   set
   {
    if ((this._idUsuario != value))
    {
     this._idUsuario = value;
    }
     
   }
  }

Tengo eso así, pero no se donde puedo poner lo de que no me retorne un null en ese campo

Comment: fijate en el set, le estas diciendo: *Si este usuario no es valor, entonces este usuario es igual a valor*

Comment: Los cambios que pruebes/hagas, agregalos a la publicación, que en comentarios no es simple leerlo.

Comment: Y como debería de modificar el set para que me funcionase con valores nulos??

Comment: No funcionará un INT con valores nulos, es lo que te han dicho todos. Lo que debes hacer, es averiguar por que esta llegando un NULL cuando debería llegar un INT

Answer (score 0):

Nunca se puede ejecutar un metodo si tiene valores null, por eso hay condicionales que te permiten verificar que no sea null y no te rompa el programa.
En tu caso estas tratando de convertir a entero un valor null y te va a romper siempre, deberias chequear que no lleve null y si tu prodecimiento te lo permite le pasas un 0 en caso no tener algun valor.

Suponiendo que llamas a un metodo, podes colocar esos dos valores como opcionales en tus parametros.

```
public List<TuClase> Obtener (string tokenUsuario, int idPrueba = 0, int idEstado=0)
{
using (myApp ctx = new myApp())
    {
        var query = ctx.MY_STORED_PROCEDURE(tokenUsuario, idPrueba, idEstado);

        var jsonString = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       listadoIncidencias = jsonString.Serialize(query);    
    }
}
```

Al darle un valor por defecto no estas obligado pasarle esos dos parametros
Entonces podes llamar a ese metodo de estas maneras;

```
  Obtener ("asdaCASDad<zxc");
  Obtener ("asdaCASDad<zxc", 215);
  Obtener ("asdaCASDad<zxc", 123131 ,312);
```

Edicion:

Si el problema es al recibir tu modelo debe permitir valores null

```
public class MiClase
{
   public int? Numero {get;set;} //Agregando el ? luego del tipo de la variable te permite recibir valores null.
}
```

Comment: Buenas, el problema está al recibir los datos no al enviarlos

Comment: `Nunca se puede ejecutar un metodo si tiene valores null, por eso hay condicionales que te permiten verificar que no sea null y no te rompa el programa.`- que verifiques que la carga no sea NULL, o si es NULL, que analices por que esa carga llega NULL.

Comment: Entonces en mi código:

public List<TuClase> Obtener (string tokenUsuario, int idPrueba = 0, int idEstado=0)
{
using (myApp ctx = new myApp())
    {
        var query = ctx.MY_STORED_PROCEDURE(tokenUsuario, idPrueba, idEstado);

        var jsonString = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       listadoIncidencias = jsonString.Serialize(query);    
    }
}

que debo de cambiar para que me funcione? Muchas gracias

Comment: Si el problema es cuando recibes, debes cambiar el modelo que recibe para que permitas valores null, seguramente el problema es cuando le asignas el valor obtenido a tu List listadoIncidencias, en el modelo o clase que usas para tu listado debes agregar ? como te mostre en la propiedad que cree.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando sucede eso, puedes probar hacer algo como esto:

```
                int idPrueba = 0;
                int.TryParse(dr["idPrueba"].ToString(), out idPrueba);
                //en este caso, dr["idPrueba"] uso un DataReader para la consulta en SQL
```